# iOS Swift: SQLite.swift Error - Header not found

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sqlite.swift

After following the installation instructions here:
https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

i get following error on building the project:

*unextended-module.modulemap*

```
Header not found:
'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h'
```

The issue seems to be that my Xcode is in directory Xcode-beta.app.
I tried changing the path in above file, to /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/... but the file seems to get overwritten automatically on build.'

How do i resolve this?

Comment: clean your project and delete derived data

Comment: Memon> How does one clean project and delete derived data? Sorry i am new to iOS, Xcode world.

Comment: Go Product -> Clean for clean project

Comment: if you use Xcode 6.3  then go Window -> Projects and select your project name and press delete

Comment: if you use older Xcode version then go Window -> Organizer  and select your project name and press delete

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, module maps appear to have to reference files that are absolute rather than relative to the current build SDK. Because of this, the Xcode path must be hard-coded. If you're building for Xcode 6.4 beta, please edit the **module.modulemap** file and replace "Xcode.app" with "Xcode-beta.app":

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/743530d1e56c86b5cd4df5153839a98ecb05bf5f/SQLite/module.modulemap

I've generally had a beta branch in the past and will try to cut one soon in the future.